# Why I can't curl to a remote service from my docker container

Tags: docker, curl, docker-network

I have a docker container which is running within a multi-container setup using docker-compose, it is running as a web server and is exposing port 80. (80:80) and it is running normally and I have no issues with the website or connections to the db ( which is on another container within the same network with bridge type)

**I am trying to execute a request to a remote service/API which works on a different port (8484)** like the following ex:

```
curl -X GET "http://10.10.110.110:8484/someURI/v1/getSomeData?param=value" -H "accept: application/json"
```

When I try to execute a curl through my PHP code or even from the attached shell, it takes a long time, and I get at the end the following error.

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

However, executing the same curl from the host machine or other machines responds directly.

I am stuck with this, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment since I don't have enough internet points but I would expect this to work but depending on where your docker container is, there could be a network firewall blocking your request. It would explain why the internal docker network is working for you but not that external piece...

Where are you running the containers? Locally or is it hosted somewhere?

Comment: The containers are running locally on my Ubuntu machine.